# Update Sql database using datagridview

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I would like to update a sql database through the datagridview when I press a button. How do i go about doing this? Any help will be appreciated.

Here is what i have done so far:

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Logins.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

        try
        {
            Connection.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE LoginsTable SET Name=@name, Surname=@surName, Username=@uname, Password=@pass, AccessLevel=@accessLevel", Connection);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "Name");
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@surName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "Surname");
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@uname", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "Username");
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@pass", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "Password");
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@accessLevel", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "AccessLevel");


            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Connection Unsucesful:" + ex.Message);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14759/VB-DataGridView-Automatically-Saving-Updates-to-a
```

All you need is to bind the datagridview in to your database and updates should happen automatically in the database when done